# How to make HttpContext available in Task called synchronously?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, async-await

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I need to implement/override some intrinsic entities like `IModelBinder.BindModel()`, `IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting()`, etc. Those methods are calling an async method, but obviously I cannot turn them into `async Task<>` to be able to use the `await` keyword.

So I wrote the following "adapter":

```cs
public static T GetResult<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
{
    var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

    var proxyTask = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        HttpContext.Current = httpContext;
        return func();
    });

    return proxyTask.Result;
}
```

which lets me call my async `GetData()`in a synchronous manner:

```cs
public static async Task<Data> GetData()
{
    if (isCached)
        return GetCachedData();

    var data = await GetOriginalData();
    SetCachedData(data);
    return data;
}

...

var data = GetResult(() => GetData());
```

Okay, it works, so I would call it a day, however as you can see, most of the time, `GetData()` runs synchronously, therefore spawning a new thread unconditionally is not good performance-wise. That was bugging me, so I have ended up with a different solution:

```cs
public static T GetResult<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
{
    var syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);

    var task = func();

    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(syncContext);

    return task.Result;
}
```

It also works, however the issue is that since `SynchronizationContext` is no longer flowing in, there is no `HttpContext` available in the called method.

I could probably work that around by putting `HttpContext.Current` into logical `CallContext` but am still wondering if there is a better way to tackle the issue? Something like customizing `SynchronizationContext.Current.CreateCopy()`.

Comment: First, read [*Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?*][1] and [*Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?*][2] by Stephan Toub.

Comment: Why do you think you need to call your async APIs in a sync manner?

Comment: @PauloMorgado, the links are broken. Like I said, I need to implement `object IModelBinder.BindModel()`, `void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting()`, `bool IRouteConstraint.Match()` and others, which does not leave me any choice.

Comment: I wonder what happen. The links are from the PFX Team's blog (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/). You might what to also look at Stephen Cleary's blog (http://blog.stephencleary.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> spawning a new thread unconditionally

Actually, just borrowing a thread briefly from the thread pool. Not nearly as bad as starting a new thread, but still not the best performance-wise.

> It also works, however the issue is that since SynchronizationContext is no longer flowing in, there is no HttpContext available in the called method.

Are you sure? I would expect `HttpContext.Current` to be set at the beginning of `GetData` for *both* ways to call it. I would also expect `HttpContext.Current` to be `null` after the `await` for *both* ways to call it. If it's *not* `null` after `await` in your testing, it's probably because the continuation just happened to end up on the same thread.

This is one of the main problems with trying to use `HttpContext.Current` outside of the request context (`SynchronizationContext`). When you place it on a bare thread (`Task.Run`), it will just stay there until that thread enters another request context.

> I could probably work that around by putting HttpContext.Current into logical CallContext

I would recommend pulling out whatever data you need from `Current` while on the original request context, and then passing that data in explicitly to the methods that need it.

Regarding the original problem (avoiding the extra thread in the synchronous case), I'd recommend just adding a synchronous `TryGetData` method.